# How can I customize the mui-material datagrid header outline?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the design of Mui Datagrid outline
from
[image: 1]

to
[image: 2]

I can't upload the code for some reason, is there any reference material or example code?

Answer (score 13):

simplest way to customize the datagrid is using `sx` props. you can check all the available css rules on https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#css

to remove datagrid border use `.MuiDataGrid-root` rule and inside it you can add border properties. I see you have removed column separator too. To do so use  `.MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator`

if you check below code I have prefixed `.MuiDataGrid-root` with `&` sign. but haven't added `&` sign to `.MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator`. you can open your chrome developer tool and see if the associated CSS rule has any parent class attached to it or not. if it has any you can prefix the rule with `&`. this way you don't have to write full class rule.

```
<DataGrid
  ...
  sx={{
    '.MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator': {
      display: 'none',
    },
    '&.MuiDataGrid-root': {
      border: 'none',
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

MUI Data Grid Header Styling

```
const columns: GridColumns = [
  {
    field: 'first',
    headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header',
    headerAlign: 'center',
  },
  {
    field: 'last',
    headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header',
    headerAlign: 'center',
  },
];
```

More examples with below link
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/